# Inserting values into different database using select and union

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to insert three column's values (v1, v2, v3) from three different tables (v1 from table1, v2 from table2, v3 from table3) into `db1.dest_table` from another `db2`.

Schema is ready at destination. I want to insert the values into another database table. I did union and used select statement and then tried to insert.

But after executing the below code I get this error:

> Msg 120, Level 15, State 1, Line 63
>   The select list for the INSERT statement contains fewer items than the insert list. The number of SELECT values must match the number of INSERT columns.

```
INSERT INTO dffwarehouse.[dbo].[dest_table] (v1, v2, v3)
    SELECT v1 FROM [dbo].[table1]
    UNION ALL
    SELECT v2 FROM [dbo].[table2]
    UNION ALL
    SELECT v3 FROM [dbo].[table3];
```

I want columns `(v1, v2, v3)` in database `db2`, table `dest_table`.

Comment: You're trying to INSERT into 3 columns, but the SELECT returns only 1 column.

Comment: Is there any relationship between the three tables?

Comment: How are the information from the 3 tables related?

Comment: Start with writing a SELECT that returns the 3 columns as you want them. Then use it doing the INSERT.

Comment: Make it possible to assist you: [mcve]

Comment: There is no relationship between tables.@Tim and @GMB

Comment: How will the final code look?Or any template code @jarlh can you give me?

Comment: I can't, because you haven't told us what you want. Read [mcve] one more time.

Comment: Thank you. I got your point.Your suggestion worked. I inserted using single select statement.

Answer (score 1):

Sample data and desired results would help.  If you want each value in a separate columns, with the other values `NULL`, then you can use `UNION ALL`:

```
INSERT INTO dffwarehouse.[dbo].[dest_table] (v1, v2, v3)
    SELECT v1, NULL, NULL FROM [dbo].[table1]
    UNION ALL
    SELECT NULL, v2, NULL FROM [dbo].[table2]
    UNION ALL
    SELECT NULL, NULL, v3 FROM [dbo].[table3];
```

If you want all combinations, use `CROSS JOIN`:

```
INSERT INTO dffwarehouse.[dbo].[dest_table] (v1, v2, v3)
    SELECT t1.v1, t2.v2, t3.v3
    FROM [dbo].[table1] t1 CROSS JOIN
         [dbo].[table2] t2 CROSS JOIN
         [dbo].[table3] t3;
```

Comment: I cannot use join because there is no common column between tables to join them.

Comment: I am stuck because of this error :Msg 121, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
The select list for the INSERT statement contains more items than the insert list. The number of SELECT values must match the number of INSERT columns. But selected column no and inserted column no is same I checked it many times.

Comment: All column names are correct,their data types are correct and even the order in which I am inserting is correct. I don't understand why is it showing me the same error yet...

Answer (score 0):

You could use inner join if there any relationship between those tables.

Comment: No common coloumn ...no relationship